# "fuse", "melt", "regroup" pandas dataframes almost identical rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
            id       date  tmax  tmin
12    MX17004  2010-02-02  27.3   NaN
13    MX17004  2010-02-02   NaN  14.4
22    MX17004  2010-02-03  24.1   NaN
23    MX17004  2010-02-03   NaN  14.4
44    MX17004  2010-03-05  32.1   NaN
45    MX17004  2010-03-05   NaN  14.2
```

As you can see, every date has two rows, one with a tmax (and a NAN for tmin) and the other one that has a tmin but a np.NAN value for tmax.

How could I regroup these rows? I could use a for loop but there must be a function somewhere that takes care of this case?

edit : desired output :

```
            id       date  tmax  tmin
12    MX17004  2010-02-02  27.3  14.4
22    MX17004  2010-02-03  24.1  14.4
44    MX17004  2010-03-05  32.1  14.2
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it will indeed be clearer that way ! I'll edit the original post to add it !

Comment: @Benjamin does `df.groupby(['id', 'date'], as_index=False).first()` do what you're after?

Comment: @JonClements : It actually does ! I had the idea of a groupby but couldn't print what I wanted. I'll take a look at "as_index" and ".first()" to understand precisely what it does ! Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: Great - I won't answer at the moment... I'm trying to find where this has already been answered and explained in detail... (if I recall - that question/answer also had alternate methods which are useful in similar but slightly varying situations...)